# When are extra columns removed in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I understand that the order of operations for SQL in Teradata is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

This is from [this link](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Query-execution-order/m-p/70588#M29456).

Does this mean that any extra, unneeded columns in the tables I am joining are **always** removed at the very end (when SELECT is performed)? Do those extra unselected columns take up spool space until they are finally dropped?

So if I am joining Table A (5 columns) with Table B (10 columns), the intermediate result right after the join is 14 columns (with 1 common key). But let's say I'm ultimately only selecting 3 columns at the end.

Does the query optimizer always include all 14 columns in the intermediate result (thus taking up spool space) or is it smart enough to only include the needed 3 columns in the intermediate result?

If it is smart enough to do this, then I could save spool space by rewriting every table I'm joining to as a subquery of ONLY the columns I need from that table.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the compiling and execution of queries.

Those are not the "order of operations".  What you have described is the order of "interpreting the query".  This occurs during the compilation phase, when the identifiers (column and table names and aliases) are interpreted.

SQL is a *descriptive* language.  A SQL query *describes* the result set.  It does not describe *how* the data is processed (a *procedural* language would do that).

As for not reading columns.  Teradata is probably smart enough to read the columns it needs from the data pages and not bring along unreferenced columns throughout the processing.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Couldn't we say that changing how a SQL query is written can change how it is processed? For example, filtering in a WHERE clause versus filtering on a JOIN is processed differently.

Ultimately I'm trying to avoid spool space errors and wanted to see if it's worth substituting smaller subqueries in each join.

Comment: For inner joins, filter predicates in ON or WHERE clauses are equivalent. For outer joins, they are different. Subqueries that simply project a subset of rows and columns from a single table are generally eliminated by the optimizer and the predicates merged into the outer query.

Comment: And yes, the optimizer is smart enough to only copy columns to spool if needed for the answer set or for later query steps.

Comment: Ok thanks Fred, so it sounds like I won't be saving any spool space by doing these subqueries. Will look for other methods. Appreciate it.